# How can you convert AC voltage readings to DC voltage readings

Tags: voltage

One of my crews had been sent out to get DC battery voltage readings but they had the volt meter set on AC. I need to convert the readings to DC so I can submit the information.

Comment: Sorry there is no connection... send them out again and have them set the meter correctly.

Comment: Don't employ untrained staff. If you think they were trained then don't employ morons. If you believe you are unable to avoid morons being selected at the job interview then you should consider your own usefullness in that interview.

Comment: It's too unpredictable and depends on the meter. Most proper meters will display 0v for DC with AC set, others will read the peak, others may read the rms regardless of the setting... If any reading was achieved, it may have been the ripple in the DC. Basically, have them measure again.

Answer (score 1):

Most meters will read 0 when using the AC setting to measure DC, although there have been reports of some cheap DVMs reading much higher than the actual DC voltage when set to AC.

The best thing to do is to send the crews out again, with instructions to set the meter to DC when taking DC readings.

You might get away with testing the meter in the shop to see what DC voltage gives the recorded "AC" reading.

Answer (score 0):

Run your DVM on a known DC volt source like a lab supply and flick the DVM to AC now you can get a calibration factor which will depend a little bit on the meter.You can correct your crews data with your derived calibration factor and submit the data if it looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

Set the voltmeter to the same settings they used, then connect a DC supply across the meter and increase the supply's output voltage until the meter reads what your crew reported.

Then, disconnect the meter from the supply without disturbing the supply, switch the meter to DC VOLTS and reconnect it to the supply.

The reading you get will be what they would have gotten in the field if the meter had been set to DC VOLTS.

Answer (score 0):

Cheap DMM measures mean value of AC signal, but displays the effective value - Vrms. When the AC signal is pure sine wave then Vrms = 1.11 * V_average, all those DMMs presume that AC signal is always pure sine (which is not always true) and calculate the effective value by multiplying the average value with factor of 1.11. More costly DMM have TrueRMS feature.
From your description, you measured DC signal with AC setting on DMM, therefore probably the measuring is 1.11 more than actual, beacuse the mean value of DC signal is the same as magnitude of DC signal. You can use your DMM and measure a battery voltage with AC, then switch to DC and calculte the factor.